# Outlook mailitem.sender generates error 287 in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, outlook, mailitem

I am trying to pull details of Outlook mail items in a shared mailbox.

To make it easier for colleagues I created the macro in Excel.

It is falling down at:

```
sender = olItem.sender
```

In Outlook VBA it pulls through the name of the sender of the email.

In Excel it causes a

> Runtime Error 287 Application-Defined or User-Defined error

This happens for every message. If I remove/comment out the erroring line of code then it successfully pulls out the subject lines and received dates and times.

```
Sub GetEmailData()

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim NS As Outlook.Namespace
Dim Inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim objOwner As Outlook.Recipient
Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim subject As String
Dim sender As String
Dim senddate As String
Dim homebook As Workbook, homesheet As Worksheet

Set homebook = Workbooks("Email Log.xlsm")
Set homesheet = homebook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

'Clear contents
homesheet.Range("A4:D100").Delete

Set olApp = Outlook.Application

Set NS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objOwner = NS.CreateRecipient("***email address of mailbox***")
Set Inbox = NS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objOwner, olFolderInbox)

n = 4

For Each olItem In Inbox.Items
    subject = olItem.subject
    sender = olItem.sender
    senddate = olItem.ReceivedTime
    homesheet.Range("B" & n).Value = subject
    homesheet.Range("C" & n).Value = sender
    homesheet.Range("A" & n).Value = senddate
    n = n + 1
Next

homesheet.Range("A1").Value = "Last Updated: " & Now()
homesheet.Range("A2").Value = "Number of Items: " & Inbox.Items.Count

End Sub
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error.  Does your inbox contain any items without a sender?  It's possible to store files, notes and drafts in any mailbox.

Comment: I can confirm that the mailbox only contains emails which have been received in and all have senders.

Comment: if the code works ok for you destination-data then do you think that the problem is with the Excel setup on my machine? E.g. what libraries i have enabled etc?

Comment: Does this happen only for a particular message? Does it happen after you process a large (100+) number items?

Comment: No this happens for every message and they're only kb's in size with no attachments. If i remove/comment out the erroring line of code then the rest works fine at it sucessfully pulls out the subject lines and recieved dates and times.